# How to reference a global function in a Vue component?

Tags: javascript, function, vue.js

I have a Vue component that has a 'select state' dropdown element. I want to add a js function that populates the options with the 50 states instead of having to hard code them. I will also have this dropdown in a couple other places so I want this function to be accessed from outside the component. What is the best way to accomplish this?

```
<template>
    <div class="section" v-bind:class="sectionClass" data-mh="group3"> 
        <h3>{{sectionTitle}}</h3> 
        <div class="section-content display-area"> 
            <i class="icon icon-health img-left"></i> 
            <form> 
            <div class="row mt"> 
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8"> 
                  <div class="same-height-parent"> 
                      <div class="same-height"> 
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name"> 
                      </div>                                                 
                      <div class="same-height"> 
                          <select name="state" id="state" class="form-control" tabindex="9"> 
                              <option value="">- Select State -</option>
                          </select>                                                     
                      </div>                                                 
                  </div>                                             
                  <!-- same-height-parent -->                                             
                </div>                                         
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4"> 
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-fz20">Search</button>
                  </div>                                         
               </div>                                                                       
            </form>                                 
        </div>              
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'nameSearch',
        data: function() {
            return {
                sectionTitle: 'Name Search'=
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Find a json file with the states, add it to your project, and import it.

Comment: This sounds like you could make a [mixin](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you may want to export the function from some other file, this is simply a case of declaring it the way you want.

in some other file...

```
// utils.js
export function createOptions (someArg) {
  let options = [ ... ]
  return options
}
```

in your .vue file

```
<script>
  import { createOptions } from './utils'
  export default {
    ...
    data () {
      return {
        options: createOptions()
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

You may also want to try snovakovic's advice to externalise the dropdown component instead, whatever brings you more flexibility

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create states components that handles drop-down and then include that component everywhere where it's used.

If you want just a function then create js file that expose that function and than import that file inside component.